# Como somar vários intervalos de data como php

Tags: php, datetime

Estou com um problema relacionado à soma de datas.
Tenho vários eventos que são cadastrados no banco com data inicial e data final, eu preciso saber o intervalo de tempo entre esses eventos e somar esses intervalos para saber o total de tempo que duraram esses eventos. Para calcular a diferença de tempo de um evento utilizo o método `diff` da classe `DateTime`, porém não consigo somar esse intervalos. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue abaixo o código:

```
$intervalo1 = date_diff($objDataInicio1, $objDataFim1);
$intervalo2 = date_diff($objDataInicio2, $objDataFim2);
$somaDosIntervalos = $intervalo1+$intervalo2 ?????
```

Até consigo fazer a soma dos números de dias, meses e anos, mas isso não funciona por que o valor somado é como inteiro não como data, então, se tiver 25 dias no primeiro intervalo e 20 dias no segundo o resultado do calculo será 45 dias, não 1 mês e 15 dias.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode realizar isso utilizando o método [`diff` do objeto DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R');
echo $interval->format('%a');

// Diferença de dias do primeiro intervalo de datas
$s = $interval->format('%R');
$d1 = $interval->format('%a') * ($s == '-' ? -1 : 1); 

echo PHP_EOL;

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-05');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R');
echo $interval->format('%a');

// Diferença de dias do primeiro intervalo de datas
$s = $interval->format('%R');
$d2 = $interval->format('%a') * ($s == '-' ? -1 : 1);

echo PHP_EOL;

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-25');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R');
echo $interval->format('%a');

// Diferença de dias do primeiro intervalo de datas    
$s = $interval->format('%R');
$d3 = $interval->format('%a') * ($s == '-' ? -1 : 1);

echo PHP_EOL;

echo 'Soma do intervalo: ' . ($d1 + $d2 + $d3) . ' dias';
```

Saída:

```
+2
-6
+14
Soma do intervalo: 10 dias
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data1 = new DateTime( '2013-12-11' );
$data2 = new DateTime( '1994-04-17' );

$intervalo = $data1->diff( $data2 );

echo "Intervalo é de {$intervalo->y} anos, {$intervalo->m} meses e     {$intervalo->d} dias";
```

Comment: Vanderson, isso eu tinha feito, mas eu quero somar os diff de vários datas diferentes